# Why are my textures appearing correctly on material view, but not on soild?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, unity, viewlayers

I'm trying to put together some assets to make a vrchat model for myself. Everything appeared to be great on the model, but when I checked the solid view, I noticed that the front of my model's shoes were transparent. I thought maybe it would be okay because the shoes looked fine in material and rendered view. I loaded the model into unity and it shows the shoes' front transparent like it did in the solid mode. This is my second day of using blender and I can't seem to find the solution. Any tips?[image]

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I would, but I don't think I can because the assets I'm using are purchased and they have DMCA stuff, so I'm not sure how that would work with sharing the file

Comment: have you checked for overlapping geometry, normals orientation?

Comment: The *Solid* mode uses the *Workbench* render engine which uses not the *Material Properties > Surface* colors but the settings under *Material Properties > Viewport Display*. Also, check the options for the viewport shading (dropdown menu right next to the shading icons). https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html#solid

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by recalculating the normals to face the outside.